# template argument '(type)0' does not match 'EnumValue'

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-bug

Given this C++11 code:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum Enum { EnumValue };

template <typename>
struct Pred { constexpr static bool const value = true; };

template <
        typename T,
        typename ::std::enable_if<
            Pred<T>::value,
            Enum
        >::type = EnumValue>
class Huh {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool f(Huh<T> const &) noexcept { return true; }

static_assert(f(Huh<int>()), "");
```

I get the following error message from GCC 7.3.0:

```
test.cpp:19:27: error: no matching function for call to 'f(Huh<int>)'
 static_assert(f(Huh<int>()), "");
                           ^
test.cpp:17:16: note: candidate: template<class T> constexpr bool f(const Huh<T>&)
 constexpr bool f(Huh<T> const &) noexcept { return true; }
                ^
test.cpp:17:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:19:27: note:   template argument '(type)0' does not match 'EnumValue'
 static_assert(f(Huh<int>()), "");
                           ^
```

If I use `int` and `0` instead of `Enum` and `EnumValue`, the error is gone. **Why does this fail with an enum?**

Comment: Looks like a bug.  gcc 8.x+ compiles as does clang

Comment: It compiles for me with both G++ 8.2.1 and Clang++ 6.0.1. Maybe it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Reproduced with MinGW g++ 7.3.0. It looks like it's unable to handle the two levels of templating. Manages to handle one level.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about how to work around this on broken versions of GCC while keeping the enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea about how to work around this on broken versions of GCC while keeping the enum?

You can grit your teeth and tell the compiler what it fails to deduce:

```
static_assert(f<int>(Huh<int>()), "");
```

[Success](https://godbolt.org/z/qOZKQg)

If the unsightliness would be widespread maybe you can localize it in some conditionally compiled wrapping.